# How to get the row when a date condition is set in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

How can I filter the data range by having a specific date?

I have a SpreadSheet with some credit data of mine. I would like to Google Sheets filter and say to me which sum value needs to be paid in this month.

Example: I have ID 18 that still needs payment because my credit card is due to 20/07. But ID 14 should also appear because I didn't pay all  6 installments. So suming the installments values (column J) it would be R$ 312,88 due to this month. This 312,88 would be shown in some cell beucase is the value that I need to pay this month.

I know this sounds complicated, but I would be very thankful for any help.

[image]

Comment: So you want the values in column J to be added where rows have "P" in Column D?

Comment: Can you make a copy of that sheet for me to mess around it?

Comment: Could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, and indicate clearly what is the desired outcome? (remove all sensitive information)

Answer (score 0):

Are you after a filter or do you just need the sum?

If just sum, can we base the calc on the "p" in column D? - it appears the "p" is common. If so, try:

```
=sumif(D3:D,"p",J3:J)
```

If you would like the value to only show when a payment is due, try:

```
=iferror(if(search("p",concatenate(D3:D)),sumif(D3:D,"p",J3:J)),"No Payment Due")
```

You can indeed also filter by dates, but please precisely explain the input and result logic desired.